# CSS image darken adding extra 7px to bottom

Tags: html, css, image

I have some images that I use CSS to make a darker background.
This makes the images darken on hover. It can be seen at *rtsb.co.uk* on the main images.

However when viewing the images, the background is shown slightly behind the images, seen as a grey stripe under each image. the images are 600px height, but for some reason, the code for 'outerLink' makes it 607px height and so the bar appears, this can be seen using Chrome dev tools when viewing the page.

```css
.outerLink {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
img.darkableImage {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

```html
<a href="/collections/sale" class="outerLink">
  <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1234/4330/t/6/assets/promo_image_1.jpg?12217915569807539649" alt="Sale" class="darkableImage" onmouseout="this.style.opacity=1;" onmouseover="style.opacity=0.7;">
</a>
```

I've tried looking at everything to find where this added 7px comes from but I can't find it anywhere.

Even if I change the name of the CSS to .outerLinktest, the  tag above still seems to pick up a height of 19px from somewhere.

I cannot add a height CSS attribute to .outerLink as the page is dynamic for mobiles etc and the images resize due to this so won't always be 600px high.

Comment: Can you provide some example about what are you expecting and what are you getting? I made a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jc9hg272/ but I cannot see what you mean because in my case the grey background appears on the image.

Comment: How does the additional 7px matter? The image you are using is 407x600.

Comment: @Bera check my answer below..

Comment: @Ani, because the image background is white, and the rollover is light grey, this result(ed) in a light grey bar of 7px below all images. however now fixed with Sunil's answer.

Comment: In case you wondered why this happens: The image by default is alined in the text flow (`vertical-align: baseline`). The black bar you see is the space between the bottom of the link and the baseline of the text. You already got two working answers, but another one would be to add `vertical-align: bottom` to the image. With that knowledge you can pick the answer that causes the least side effects for your situation, or even come up with alternative solutions by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `display:block;` on img class.

```
img.darkableImage 
{
    opacity:1;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
    display:block;
}
```

Snippet:

```css
.outerLink 
    {
        background-color:#e8e8e8; 
        display:block; 
        opacity:1;
        filter:alpha(opacity=100);
    }

    img.darkableImage 
    {
        opacity:1;
        filter:alpha(opacity=100);
        display:block;
    }
```

```html
<a href="/collections/sale" class="outerLink">
    <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1234/4330/t/6/assets/promo_image_1.jpg?12217915569807539649" alt="Sale" class="darkableImage" onmouseout="this.style.opacity=1;" onmouseover="style.opacity=0.7;">
</a>
```

Check [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8a5mn3wg/)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to put

```
display:flex;
```

instead of

```
display:block;
```

in outerLink?

```
.outerLink {
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
    display: flex;
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

I've tried it with the inspector and it works.

Snippet:

```css
.outerLink {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  display: flex;
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
img.darkableImage {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="/collections/sale" class="outerLink">
  <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1234/4330/t/6/assets/promo_image_1.jpg?12217915569807539649" alt="Sale" class="darkableImage" onmouseout="this.style.opacity=1;" onmouseover="style.opacity=0.7;">
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

also make the image display:block;

```
img.darkableImage 
{
    opacity:1;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);

    display:block; /*<----*/
}
```

or change outerlink background color into white maybe...

Answer (score -1):

You may set position attributes to your classes :

```
.outerLink 
{
    background-color:#000; 
    display:block; 
    opacity:1;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
    position:absolute;
}

img.darkableImage 
{
    opacity:1;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
    position: relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: This is *a* solution, but a very cumbersome given the situation, and it may have a lot of side effects.